# Подгрузки load к уже имеющимся данным

Tags: java, html, jquery, ajax

Функция подгрузки данных:

```
function ShowData(event)
{
  event.preventDefault();
  $('#divTXT').load('text/company.txt');
}
```

html для подгрузки:

```
<div id = "divTXT">
    Сюда подгружаются данные TXT
</div>
```

После подгрузки исходный текст в `div` заменяется на подгруженный. Как сделать, чтобы в `div` был: исходный текст + подгруженный?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решение:

```
$.ajax({
url: "text/company.txt",
response:'text',
success: function (result) {
    $("#divTXT").append(result);
},
error: function (err) {
   alert("Ошибка");
}
});
```

Функция append подгружает данные к уже имеющимся

Comment: Подгружает `$.ajax`, а `append()` добавляет.